# Problems with fread and fwrite saving a float matrix from .dat file to array in memory

Tags: c, c99, fwrite, fread, strtok

**GOAL**

I need to:

**1.**  Write, with `fwrite`, a N*N matrix in to a binary file. The matrix is ​​stored contiguously in memory, in an array of N * N elements.

**2.** Allocate another N*N array and read with `fread` the matrix from the previously created file, saving it, element by element, in the newly created array.

**3.** Print on standard output the new array.

The first array is `float*` and the second array must be `float*` too.

**MY CODE**

This is my code, it seems to print the right matrix in the binary file but when i read it with `fread` and save it into a new array, when i print the new array it prints just `0.0 0.0 0.0 ecc`

```
void fileBinPrintMat(float* a, int dim, FILE* output){
    float x;
    for(int i = 0; i < dim; i++){
          x = a[i];
          fwrite(&x, sizeof(float), 1, output);
    }
 }
   

     
#define DIM 512

//PART 1, PRINT THE MATRIX IN .dat FILE
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    .
    .
    .
    float* M1 = calloc(n*n, sizeof(float));
        CHECK_MEMORY(M1, "CALLOC"); //MACRO for checking allocation memory
        for(size_t i = 0; i < (n); i++)
            for(size_t j = 0; j < n; j++)
                M1[(i*n)+j] = (i+j)/2.0;
    FILE* ofpbin = fopen("mat_dump.dat", "wb");
    CHECK_OPEN_FILE(ofpbin, "mat_dump.dat");
    fileBinPrintMat(M1, n*n, ofpbin); //Function that print matrix in file.dat
    free(M1);
    fclose(ofpbin);

//PART 2, SAVE THE MATRIX PRINTED IN .dat FILE IN N*N ARRAY
    FILE* ifpbin = fopen("mat_dump.dat", "rb");
    CHECK_OPEN_FILE(ifpbin, "mat_dump.dat");
    char* buffer = calloc(DIM, sizeof(char));
    CHECK_MEMORY(buffer, "CALLOC");
    float* M2 = calloc(n*n, sizeof(float));
    CHECK_MEMORY(M2, "CALLOC"); 
//READ MATRIX FROM FILE AND WRITE IT IN ARRAY M2
    int i = 0;
    float elemBuffer;
    while(fgets(buffer, DIM, ifpbin) != NULL){
        fread(&elemBuffer, sizeof(float), 1, ifpbin);
        M2[i] = elemBuffer;
        i++;   
    }
```

P.S. I know that i must check all return values of fread ecc... I will do it later

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

Assuming `n = 4`, final output matrix must be:

```
  0.0   0.5   1.0   1.5
  0.5   1.0   1.5   2.0
  1.0   1.5   2.0   2.5
  1.5   2.0   2.5   3.0
```

in binary file is something as:

```
 ? ? �? �?
 ? �? �? @
 �? �? @  @
 �? @  @ @@
```

And i think it's ok, it must be saved from .dat to array `float* M2` like this:

```
0.0   0.5   1.0   1.5   0.5   1.0   1.5   2.0   1.0   1.5   2.0   2.5   1.5   2.0   2.5   3.0
```

**MY OUTPUT**

```
  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
```

**IMPORTANT:**

It's an univesity homework, i just can use fread and fwrite for binary file i/o and strtok for tokenize the space between elements in file.

Comment: If you are reading and writing binary data the only two functions you should be using are `fread` and `fwrite`. Why are you writing backslashes and spaces? Defeats the entire purpose of a binary file. The macros just make your code harder to read, especially here where you'd generally want to make your [mcve] as simple and easy to understand as possible.

Comment: You're right about the macros. I will edit it. About backslashes and spaces, how can i write a space in a binary file to tokenize every different number saved in it?

Comment: You don't need to tokenize them in a binary file.  Every `float` will occupy exactly 4 bytes so there is no need for any sort of separator between them.

Comment: Ok, so can't i format the file in colums just as a classic N*N matrix?

Comment: Binary files generally, will not be viewed as text files. So formatting is not required. If you want to open that file and want to see a neatly formatted matrix, then you use text files.

Comment: Also, avoid using macros for these purposes. Is anything stopping you from using functions instead? Bcoz they are lot safer.

Comment: I modified file using a function that print matrix in file.dat instead of macro, without spaces and backslashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with binary files, the rule of thumb is that the code that reads from the file, and code that writes to the file should be identical but with reverse functions.

What I mean by this is, in your case you have simple loop writing a continuous array of `float` values to file.

This means, your read code must do the same - read a continuous array of floats from file.

Adding extra logic to the read loop(s) makes you code parse the data in a wrong way, which is why you can not get the values back.

So here is how you should read them:

```
void fileBinReadMat(float* a, int dim, FILE* input){
    float x;
    for(int i = 0; i < dim; i++){
          fread(&x, sizeof(float), 1, input);
          a[i] = x;
    }
}
```

Strictly speaking, you don't need the `x` intermediate variable for reading or writing, but I left it in there to keep the code identical and easier to understand.

Comment: Ok, it works, so if i understand well, fread read 4 byte from the file and than improve pointer of 4 bytes? So i don' need to use fgets?

And i can write it also as: 

`void fileBinReadMat(float* a, int dim, FILE* input){
    for(int i = 0; i < dim; i++){
          fread(&a[i], sizeof(float), 1, input);
    }
}`

Comment: @ClaudioDeLise `fgets` is for reading strings (printable characters) not for reading `float` stored as binary, so no, you don't need it and you can't use it. I don't know what you mean by " improve pointer" but what `fread` will do is take 4 bytes from file and put them in memory to which a pointer you give it points to. You can give it the address of the array cell directly `fread(&a[i], sizeof(float), 1, input);` and it will work fine. `fread` does not care what memory to put the bytes in, as long as your program legally owns it. Don't forget to `calloc` or `malloc` the array before reading!

Comment: I try to explain you my "improve". 
I see that i pass to `fread`, as last argument a `FILE*` file; in the first iteration of `for` it takes 4 bytes and copies them in memory of pointer in first argument, that in this case is `a[0]`. How can `fread` in second iteration of `for` copy the second 4 bytes in `a[1]`. Why don't he copy the first 4 bytes again if in second iteration i'm passing `FILE*` file again?

Comment: @ClaudioDeLise Don't think of `FILE*` as a regular pointer. Think of it as "a black box for using files". It points to a file object that manages the open file. It "knows" how many bytes you read from file, and keeps the position of next bytes to read. it is all done automatically. It will not read bytes you already read, unless you move the position using `fseek` function.